# Is there a prevalent technique to sum the elements of an array having generic type but limited to Number?

Tags: java, arrays, generics

I created a generic-type array bounded with Number. I created a method to sum all of its elements.
Here is the code

```java
class GenericMethod {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Integer[] arr = {10, 20, 30, 40, 50};
        int sum = GenericMethod.<Integer>sumOfAllElements(arr);
        System.out.println(sum);
        Float[] floats = {3.0f, 4.19f};
        int sum2 = GenericMethod.<Float>sum(floats);
        System.out.println(sum2);
    }

    public static <T extends Number> int sumOfAllElements(T[] arr) {
        int response = 0;
        for (T t : arr) {
            response += t.intValue();
        }
        return response;
    }
}
```

In the method, the return type is still an `int`. I would like to change the return-type to a generic as well.

- I've tried declaring the `response` variable with the generic-type `N` but then I can't initialize it with `0` or even with the `Integer` wrapper class'
  `N result = Integer.valueOf(0);`
  which I initially thought might be possible since the `Integer` class extended the `Number` class.
- Then I tried initializing it as `null`
  `N result = null;`
  but then this line,
  `result = result + array[i].intValue();`
  throws an error stating `Operator + cannot be applied to N, int`. I can't change the line to
  `result = result + array[i];`
  because then it shows `Operator + cannot be applied to N, N`.
- I've also tried this "hack"

```java
public static <N extends Number> N sum(N[] array) {
        Number result = array[0];
        if (result instanceof Integer) {
            Integer temp = result.intValue();
            for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
                temp += array[i].intValue();
            }
            result = temp;
        }
        return (N) result;
    }
```

but then I would have to specify the cases for all Number types.
Could someone please help me with,
- modifying this method, so that it could return a generic-type instead of `int`.
- help me understand the nature and cause of this problem, is it because the class is still a non-generic type?

Comment: Are you ok with passing in additional arguments?

Comment: You wouldn't be able to perform arithmetic operations without using a concrete `Number` subclass in your implementation; so the benefits of using a generic parameter are lost anyway. Better choose one concrete subclass (like `Double` or `BigDecimal`) and make that the return type, and do calculations with that type.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The *simplest* method, if using Java 8+, would be to use `Arrays.stream(T[])` to create a stream of `T`(s) and then `reduce` that stream with addition. Like,

```
Integer[] arr = { 10, 20, 30, 40, 50 };
Float[] floats = { 3.0f, 4.19f };
System.out.println(Arrays.stream(arr).reduce((a, b) -> a + b));
System.out.println(Arrays.stream(floats).reduce((a, b) -> a + b));
```

No additional methods required. **But**, if you want to make that a method, you could pass the operation like

```
public static <T> T add(T[] arr, BinaryOperator<T> op) {
    return Arrays.stream(arr).reduce(op).get();
}
```

and then call it like

```
System.out.println(add(arr, (a, b) -> a + b));
```